# VK Android SDK - response.parsedModel is null

Tags: android, vk, vk-sdk

I'm using the latest Android SDK for VK, and trying to get posts from my wall:

```
VKParameters vkParameters = VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, SettingsManager.getInstance().getVkId());

        VKRequest vkRequest = VKApi.wall().get(vkParameters);
        vkRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);

                VKList<VKApiPost> posts = (VKList<VKApiPost>) response.parsedModel;
                for (VKApiPost post : posts) {
                    Logger.i(GuestsActivity.class, "Post: " + post.getId());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                super.onError(error);
            }
        });
```

I see the JSON and string in response, but parsedModel is null:
[image: Debugger]

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: try this dependencies , dependencies {
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.7'
}

Comment: @ExceptionLover I use the same version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add request param `extended` (and yes, i know its strangely ):

```
VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1
```